# Trouble Removing Slick Slider / Carosel Below Certain Resolution

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js, window-resize

I'm having trouble removing my slick carosel for screens below a certain resolution (768px). Here is the code I'm using (I found it here on Stack overflow). The trouble is, my slick carosel won't display at all after adding this code.

```
 $slickGreen = false;
    function greenSlider(){    
        if($(window).width() &gt; 768){
            if(!$slickGreen){
                $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick({
            slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: true,
        infinite:true
       }).show();
   
                });
                $slickGreen = true;
            }
        } else if($(window).width() &lt; 767){
            if($slickGreen){
                $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick(&#39;unslick&#39;);
                $slickGreen = false;
            }
        }
    };
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
        ....
        greenSlider();
    });
    $(window).on(&#39;resize&#39;, function(){
         ....
         greenSlider();
    });
```

My original code that does work to display the carosel is as follows:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: true,
        infinite:true
   
      }).show();
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, I have finally figured out how to do this. All of the code I used is below. Note: XML characters were used since I am using a Blogger template, which doesn't allow ' or > < signs.

```
   
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will fire when document is ready:
    $(window).on(&#39;resize&#39;, function(){
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() &gt;= 1024) {
            // if larger or equal
        $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: true,
        infinite:true
   
      }).show();

             } else if ($(window).width() &gt;= 800) {
            // if smaller
            $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick({
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
               arrows: true,
               infinite:true
   
              }).show();
   
           } else if ($(window).width() &gt;= 600) {
            // if smaller
            $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick({
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
               arrows: true,
               infinite:true
   
              }).show();
   
        } else if ($(window).width() &gt;= 300) {
            // if smaller
            $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).slick({
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 2000,
               arrows: true,
               infinite:true
   
        
   
              }).show();
   
        } else {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false
            $(&#39;#book-carosel&#39;).unslick();
        }
    }).resize(); // This will simulate a resize to trigger the initial run.
});
```